# Beamer fails with mathematics

Tags: beamer, miktex

Yesterday I bought a new laptop and installed MikTeX. Today I tried a minimal Beamer document and it failed to run. 
Other, non-Beamer, TeX files work OK. Also OK are Beamer files without mathematics. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the .tex file:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

  $\ell$     <- with only this line, no problem

   $l$       <- this line causes the whole thing to fail    

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The console output suggests that "makepk" is the culprit. Here is the start of the corresponding log file:

2018-03-10 12:36:49,678-0700 INFO  miktex-makepk - starting with command line: miktex-makepk --enable-installer --verbose mathkerncmssi8 450 600 0+450/600

2018-03-10 12:36:49,681-0700 INFO  makepk - Trying to make PK font mathkerncmssi8 at 450 DPI...

2018-03-10 12:36:49,714-0700 INFO  makepk - The METFAONT mode is: ljfour

2018-03-10 12:36:49,726-0700 INFO  makepk - Running miktex-makemf.exe...

2018-03-10 12:36:49,727-0700 INFO  makepk - running: miktex-makemf.exe --verbose mathkerncmssi8

2018-03-10 12:36:50,066-0700 INFO  makepk - Running miktex-ttf2pk.exe...

2018-03-10 12:36:50,066-0700 INFO  makepk - running: miktex-ttf2pk.exe -q -t mathkerncmssi8

2018-03-10 12:37:26,637-0700 FATAL miktex-makepk - The process terminated due to an access violation.

2018-03-10 12:37:26,637-0700 FATAL miktex-makepk - Info: fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-ttf2pk.exe"

2018-03-10 12:37:26,638-0700 FATAL miktex-makepk - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process\win\winProcess.cpp

2018-03-10 12:37:26,638-0700 FATAL miktex-makepk - Line: 435

2018-03-10 12:40:12,640-0700 INFO  miktex-makepk - starting with command line: miktex-makepk --enable-installer --verbose mathkerncmssi8 450 600 0+450/600

2018-03-10 12:40:12,643-0700 INFO  makepk - Trying to make PK font mathkerncmssi8 at 450 DPI...

2018-03-10 12:40:12,655-0700 INFO  makepk - etc.....

I'm a non-technical person so none of this makes sense to me. Is there an easy or obvious fix??

Comment: Run updmap on a command line, or run in the miktex console (user mode) the task to recreate the font maps.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have no idea what that means or how it works, but it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Would you like to convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Wow, that was fast!

Answer (score 5):

Run `updmap` on a command line.

Or run in the (new) miktex console (user mode) in the tasks menu "Refresh font map files".

Comment: I was having the same problem and this mysterious incantation fixed it (thank goodness for stackexchange). Can anyone explain what is happening here and what updmap does to fix it?